# List of Tasks C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, task

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        worker.GetHouses(currentPage);
    });

    tasks.Add(task);
    currentPage++;
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

There is something i don't understand.

Whenever i use:

```
var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Run(() => {worker.GetHouses(1);}),
        Task.Run(() => {worker.GetHouses(2);}),
        Task.Run(() => {worker.GetHouses(3);})
    };
```

And i loop trough that array, i get results perfectly fine. (when using `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`

When i use:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
```

my `Task.WaitAll(tasks.toArray())` doesn't seem to work, my tasks "Status" stays on "RanToCompletion"

What did i do wrong?

Comment: what is `Task` refering to? property or class? I can't find `Run` method in it

Answer (score 4):

You have a synchronization problem with the `currentPage` variable. Also create tasks with result.

Solution:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<List<House>>>();

for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    var currentPageCopy = currentPage; 
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return worker.GetHouses(currentPageCopy);
    });

    tasks.Add(task);
    currentPage++;
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

The problem with your code is that all `GetHouses` invocations will be called with `currentPage + pageCount - 1` as the last value will be used for all method calls...

Comment: My list of tasks still has the status "RanToCompletion, Method = "{null}", without a Result.

Comment: Return type of GetHouses = List<House>

Answer (score 0):

There's been little issue with task types.
In your sample you were using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`, which does not have the result - it's intended just to do some job, like `void` method.
In your code here:

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Run(() => {worker.GetHouses(1);}),
    Task.Run(() => {worker.GetHouses(2);}),
    Task.Run(() => {worker.GetHouses(3);})
};
```

no type were specified explicitly, so it turned out to be `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<List<House>>`, but first piece of code you specified the `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` explicitly:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
```

What you need to use is `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>`:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<List<House>>>();// <- task type specified explicitly 

for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<House>>(() =>// <- task type specified explicitly , though it's mandatory here
    {
        return worker.GetHouses(currentPage);
    });

    tasks.Add(task);
    currentPage++;
}
```

In similar situations I tend to define types explicitly, so that code becomes clearer to read and as you can see, even to work.